# Empty array messing up default argument values

Tags: ruby, oop

I'm following through the Hungry Academy curriculum using a post here: http://jumpstartlab.com/news/archives/2013/09/03/scheduling-six-months-of-classes

And I'm up to the EventReporter project found here: http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/event_reporter.html

So far I've built a simple CLI that asks for a valid command and accepts additional arguments with the command. I'm working ONLY on the load functionality right now and I'm having some trouble getting a default `listfile` variable set in `AttendeeList`s initialize method. Here's the code so far:

```
require 'csv'

class Reporter
    def initialize()
        @command = ''
        loop()
    end

#Main reporter loop
   def loop
    while @command != 'quit' do 
        printf "Enter a valid command:"
        user_command_input = gets.chomp
        user_input_args = []
        @command = user_command_input.split(" ").first.downcase
        user_input_args = user_command_input.split(" ").drop(1)
        #DEBUG - puts @command
        #DEBUG - puts user_input_args.count

        case @command
        when "load"
            attendee_list = AttendeeList.new(user_input_args[0])
        when "help"
            puts "I would print some help here."
        when "queue"
            puts "I will do queue operations here."
        when "find"
            puts "I would find something for you and queue it here."
        when "quit"
            puts "Quitting Now."
            break
        else
            puts "The command is not recognized, sorry. Try load, help, queue, or find."
        end

    end
   end

 end

class AttendeeList
    def initialize(listfile = "event_attendees.csv")
        puts "Loaded listfile #{listfile}"
    end
end

reporter = Reporter.new
```

I'm testing running the `load` command with no arguments and is see that when I initialize the `AttendeeList` that `user_input_args[0]` is an empty array `[]` which, to my understanding is not nil, so I think that's the problem. I'm a little lost on how to continue though when I want the args to be passed through to my new instance of `AttendeeList`. I'd also prefer not to include the default logic in my Reporter class since that kind of defeats the purpose of encapsulating within the list.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that `listfile` default for `AttendeeList` initialize method is argument I'm talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make this change:

```
def initialize(listfile = nil)
  listfile ||= "event_attendees.csv"
  puts "Loaded listfile #{listfile}"
end
```

#### Explanation

In fact, `user_input_args[0]` *is* `nil`, but `nil` has no special meaning for default argument values. Default values are used only if the arguments are *omitted* when calling a function.

In your case:

```
AttendeeList.new
```

would work as you expected, but

```
AttendeeList.new(user_input_args[0])
```

is effectively

```
AttendeeList.new(nil)
```

and parameter `listfile` becomes `nil`.

Comment: That's an interesting little nugget as far as nil for defaults. I thought nil was the only "nothing" in ruby, but it seems here that function(nil) is not equal to function(). That's cool. Won't forget that one, it's a little weird. Thanks for the speedy answer! Much appreciated.